# Float images to the right of div containing header, text, and link

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having trouble floating two images to the right of another div element containing a header, text, and a link. I can get the images to float right to one of these things, but not all three.

```css
    .feature1  {
    
     width: 800px;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     margin-top: 140px;
     text-align: right;
     background-color: cyan;
     display: inline-block;
     overflow:hidden;
     
    }
    
    .featuresimg {
     float:right;
    }
```

```html
    <main class="features">
     <div class="feature1 clearfix">
      <div>
       <img src="assets/image1.jpg">
       <img src="assets/image2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>
       <h4 class="feature-head">FEATURE</h4>
       <h3 class="feature-text">Donec ultrices interdum diam Nam ut est</h3>
       <a href="seemore.html" class="seemore">SEE MORE</a>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Really new to this, so appreciate any help. I've been looking at other people's questions, and can't find an answer that fits what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `flexbox`.  It is generally a better way than `float` of positioning things horizontally.  A good guide to this can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.feature1  {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;

     width: 800px;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     margin-top: 140px;
     overflow:hidden;

     text-align: right;
     background-color: cyan;
}

.feature1 > div {
   flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<main class="features">
     <div class="feature1 clearfix">
      <div>
       <h4 class="feature-head">FEATURE</h4>
       <h3 class="feature-text">Donec ultrices interdum diam Nam ut est</h3>
       <a href="seemore.html" class="seemore">SEE MORE</a>
      </div>
      <div>
       <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
       <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float `images` to  the right

```css
.feature1{
    width: 800px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 140px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: cyan;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.feature1 img {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float:right;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
main class="features">
    <div class="feature1 clearfix">
        <div>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/16/15/18/soap-bubble-1984310__340.jpg">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/07/07/06/39/bubbles-51675__340.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4 class="feature-head">FEATURE</h4>
            <h3 class="feature-text">Donec ultrices interdum diam Nam ut est</h3>
            <a href="seemore.html" class="seemore">SEE MORE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```